# Caching: What to return while updating an expired cache register that takes some time?

Tags: caching, ehcache

This question is for caching in general, but just in case, i'm using EHcache for Java.

I'm using an expiration time for some records in the cache and the pseudo-code for the cache retrieval is this.

```
getCachedCollection(key){
   cacheRegister = cache.get(key)

   if cacheRegister == null then //expired
      calculated_value = SomeDao.findObjects()//it takes 5 seconds
      cache.put(key,calculated_value)
      return calculated_value
   else
      return cacheRegister.value
   end
}
```

Calculating the value, it takes 5 seconds or more and i don't have control of this time.

The problem is that, while the value is calculated in 5 seconds, several queries to that cache are made(because they found it expired), triggering several calculation of the value, or in other words, performing several queries to the db, which are not desired.

The solution that i can think is:

1. Renew the value,invalidate the expiration (the cache will store the old value)
2. update the cache value

So the first query will renew the cache with an old value, all the other queries will return the old value(but not expired) and after some seconds, the first query will update the correct value.

My question is: 
This problem seems a common problem in caching, what are the usual solutions for this problem? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should never write to cache by yourself, instead, you should utilize a **cache loader**. I haven't worked with ehcache, but this [ehcache doc](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.4/user-guide/cache-loaders) shows that you can in runtime register or unregister a cache loader for you cache.

This way **a cache would lock the item being loaded** and wait for the calculation result in future requests.

You might also want to consider a lightweight Guava's [CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html).

Hope this helps.